# After deleting image from Google Container Registry and uploading another with the same tag, deleted one is still pulled

Tags: docker, google-container-registry

I don't know if this is intended behavior or bug in GCR.
Basically I tried do it like that:

1. Create image from local files using Docker on Windows (Linux based image).
2. Before creating image I delete all local images with the same name/tag.
3. Image is tagged like repostiory/project/name:v1
4. When testing locally image have correct versions of executables (docker run imageID).
5. Before pushing image to GCR I delete all images from GCR with the same tag/name.
6. When Trying to pull new image from GCR to example kubernetes it pull the first (ever) image uploaded under particular tag.

I want to reuse the same tag to not change config file with every test and I don't really need to store previous versions of images.

Comment: Could you provide output logs of push & pull commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're hitting the problem described in [kubernetes/kubernetes#42171](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/42171).

tl;dr, the default pull policy of kubernetes is broken by design such that you cannot reuse tags ([other than `latest`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/d02cf08e27f640f09ebd489e094176fd075f3463/pkg/apis/core/v1/defaults.go#L83)). I believe the guidance from the k8s community is to use "immutable tags", which is a bit of an oxymoron.

You have a few options:

1. Switch to using the `latest` tag, since kubernetes has hardcoded this in their [default pull policy logic](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/d02cf08e27f640f09ebd489e094176fd075f3463/pkg/apis/core/v1/defaults.go#L77-L95) (I believe in an attempt to mitigate the problem you're having).
2. Never reuse a tag.
3. Switch to explicitly using the `PullAlways` ImagePullPolicy. If you do this, you will incur a small overhead, since your node will have to check with the registry that the tag has not changed.
4. Switch to deploying by image digest with the `PullIfNotPresent` ImagePullPolicy. A more detailed explanation is in the PR I linked, but this gets you the best of both worlds.